# entity getPropertyInfo() not working

Tags: commerce, entities

I am working with the entity_metadata_wrapper, and I found online this function to display all of the wrapper's properties.

```
$billing_profile = commerce_customer_profile_load($order->commerce_customer_billing['und'][0]['profile_id']);
$billingWrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_customer', $billing_profile);
dpm($billingWrapper->getPropertyInfo());
```

However, it gives me an error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method EntityValueWrapper::getPropertyInfo()

When I googled the function, it came up as [EntityStructureWrapper::getPropertyInfo()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/EntityStructureWrapper%3a%3agetPropertyInfo/7),  where I see that its not a function of `EntityValueWrapper`, but rather `EntityStructureWrapper`.

How do I create that class instead of using the code I found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commerce customer only defines a `commerce_customer_profile` entity type (not `commerce_customer`), so changing the second line to this should fix it:

```
$billingWrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_customer_profile', $billing_profile);
```